# How do I get the PID of a conhost process associated with the batch file and cmd process that created it?

Tags: command-line-interface, windows-command-prompt, pid

Say I have several *conhost* processes that happen to be running already. Now I run a batch file, which starts a `cmd` process which, in turn, causes another *conhost* process to open up. From within the batch file

- I know I can [get the PID of that batch file's cmd process](https://serverfault.com/questions/126502/how-to-get-own-process-pid-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows), but
- I don't know how to **get the `PID` of the associated *conhost* process**.

My goal is to be able to close down all the other *conhost* processes that were running previously (or possibly after the batch file was run) and not close the *conhost* associated with the very batch file and `cmd.exe` doing all the closing. If that *conhost* gets closed, so will its `cmd` process and the batch file will end prematurely (I want it to do other things after that).

This is not a duplicate of the question asked in the link above. That question only dealt with getting the `pid` of the `cmd`, not **the associated *conhost* `PID`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet could lead to solution:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
::: get my own process ID - use any method
::: applied here: altered TonyRoth's answer https://serverfault.com/a/126643/257436
set "_title=a885974x%random%"
title %_title%
for /f "tokens=2" %%G in ('tasklist /V ^| findstr "%_title%"') do (
    set "_myProcessID=%%~G"
)

::: get the associated conhost process ID
set "_wQuery=ParentProcessId=%_myProcessID% and Name='conhost.exe'"
::: debug ::: wmic process where "%_wQuery%" get Name, ProcessId, WindowsVersion
for /f "usebackq" %%G in (`
  wmic process where "%_wQuery%" get ProcessId^, WindowsVersion^|findstr /R "[0-9]"
`) do set "_myConhostID=%%~G"

::: propagate results
set _my
```

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I was looking (and asking) for. You seem to be the only one who understands that I was asking mainly for the second part - getting the associated conhost PID. Now I just need to understand how it works. I'm really a novice about this stuff.

Comment: You are welcome. Next, consider asking at stackoverflow.com site. Read both https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Microsoft tool called Process Explorer to find the active processes. You can find the process by dragging the target symbol over the windows you want the get the PID.

[image]

Comment: That's a manual process and the purpose of the batch script is to kill all the other conhost.exe's automatically. I need the batch script to be able to figure out what its conhost PID is, not me.